# Mysql string concatenation only when the value exists

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
table1: ID, object1, object2, object3
```

I want to concatenate the `object1, object2 and object3` only when the value exists in all the objects.

For example:

```
select ID, object1 +'\'+ Object2 +'\'+ object3 from table1
```

I want this query to be true only when values are present in all the objects.

The result from the above query when there is no value in object 2 and object 3 would be something like:

```
object1\\
```

But I want the output to be only as (when no value in object2 and object3)

```
object1 (without back slashes)
```

I want to avoid scenarios that arise from above query when there is no value present in object2 and object3. How do i write a query to dynamically concatenate based on the values availability?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be easy to mix `CONCAT` and `IF`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat_ws`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws). It will automatically skip nulls.

```
mysql> select concat_ws('\\', 'foo', 'bar', null, 'baz');
+--------------------------------------------+
| concat_ws('\\', 'foo', 'bar', null, 'baz') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| foo\bar\baz                                |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

However it will not skip blanks.

```
mysql> select concat_ws('\\', 'foo', 'bar', '', 'baz');
+------------------------------------------+
| concat_ws('\\', 'foo', 'bar', '', 'baz') |
+------------------------------------------+
| foo\bar\\baz                             |
+------------------------------------------+
```

A good schema will not treat nulls and `''` the same. But sometimes you don't have a choice. In that case use [`nullif`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) to turn blanks into nulls.

```
mysql> set @var = '';
mysql> select concat_ws('\\', 'foo', 'bar', nullif(@var, ''), 'baz');
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| concat_ws('\\', 'foo', 'bar', nullif(@var, ''), 'baz') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| foo\bar\baz                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

And you might want to turn that all into a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).